# First day not included between 2 dates

Tags: php

i am trying to select between to date for example between 04/05/20 and 04/07/20 but the problem is it shows only between 04/06/20 to 04/07/20 the first day is not included, can anyone help me? here is the code below:

```
include('../connect.php');
$d1=$_GET['d1'];
$d2=$_GET['d2'];     
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date <= :a and date >= :b ORDER by transaction_id DESC ");
$result->bindParam(':a', $d2);
$result->bindParam(':b', $d1);
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
```

Comment: Please show what $d1 and $d2 contain

Comment: Is the `date` column a DATE or DATETIME data type? Or is it a string of some sort

Comment: From: </font><input type="text" style="width: 223px; padding:14px;" name="d1" class="tcal" value="">To: <input type="text" style="width: 223px; padding:14px;" name="d2" class="tcal" value="" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is true check your send params and tables

notic: i advise use datetime in that format : "Y-m-d H:i:s"